# Skipping functions during deserialization

Tags: mongodb

I want to skip (not call) a function during deserialization to the object. For instance, if I have a property.

```
private int _value1 
public int Value1 
{
   get { return _value1; }
   set { 
       _value1 = value;
       CallSomeFunction(_value1) 
   }
}
```

I want to not call the "CallSomeFunction(x)" during deserialization. Because the deserialization is setting Value1, it is calling CallSomeFunction that really shouldn't be called because the CallSomeFunction already did its job when the object was created manually before. Is there a way to do this so that it skips/not calls a function in a set property and just sets the value only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, during deserialization driver call setter to initialize property, just put your function in another place and call it before save:

```
MyClass
{
  public int Value1 {get;set;}

  public void CallSomeFunction(int value);
}

var item = new MyClass();
item.Value1 = CallSomeFunction(someValue);
Save(item);
```